# Unexpected T_STRING in PHPWebSocket

Tags: php, html, websocket, phpwebsocket

I was trying to test some HTML5 WebSockets using [phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/), but I got an error while trying to execute the server script:

> Nathan-Campos-MacBook-Pro:socket Nathan$ php -q server.php
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/socket/server.php on line 109
>   Nathan-Campos-MacBook-Pro:socket Nathan$

What I should make to correct the error?

---

I'm using PHP 5.3.3 and here is the content of line 109:

```
socket_close($user->socket);
```

Comment: Two questions: What version of PHP are you using, and what's on line 109 of `server.php`?

Comment: Sorry. I've added he information now :)

Comment: It looks like a problem occurred when you downloaded it.  When I [look at the source](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/source/browse/trunk/%20phpwebsocket/server.php) you posted, it looks fine.  try posting 5 or 10 lines before hand (like 100 -> 109), since the cause of the error is likely earlier...

Comment: Here you can see the entire source: http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/source/browse/trunk/%20phpwebsocket/server.php

Comment: @nathan: I saw that (and linked to in it my reply), I'm looking for what **you** have on those lines, since that links content looks fine (to me at least)...

Comment: You've tested them on your machine? Because I'm starting to think that it's an incompatibility problem with something...

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. this is How I solve it. copy all the code in server.php and paste it in Eclipse in which you create a untitle php file. then you can inspect the line 109, where there are three extra dots, remove them and update what you have. i am sure this will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the format problem when you copy the server.php code. first time, I copy the code from [Editor Panel](https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/source/browse/trunk/+phpwebsocket/server.php?edit=1), this problem was occured. so I had make a new copy from [here](https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/source/browse/trunk/%20phpwebsocket/server.php), and successed to run the server.php :)